# Calculate Day of a week for current year from Moment

Tags: reactjs

I am making a Alarm System for Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri Sat and Sun separate. Let's say i am setting an alarm for Tuesday than i need all Tuesdays of current Month and atleast for current year till the alarm is Off. I want to achieve it using moment.

I am using Package - 'moment-weekdaysin', this is not giving me proper result. It is giving me incorrect date.

```
 code - moment().weekdaysInMonth('Monday')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What result are you getting that is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used `moment-weedaysin` before but it should share most of the same API as core `moment`. The code below will capture all Tuesday dates in the format of Month-Day-Year (MM-DD-YYY) from the current date til the end of the current year. You can change the parameter for any other days 1-7 (Monday-Sunday).

```
import moment from 'moment';

const getOccurrencesOfDayThisYear = (day = 1) => {
  let startDate = moment();
  const endOfYear = moment().endOf('year');
  const extractedDates = [];

  while (startDate.isBefore(endOfYear)) {
    if (moment(startDate).day() == day) {
      extractedDates.push(moment(startDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
    }

    startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days');
  }
  
  return extractedDates;
};

// 2 represents Tuesday; 1 being Monday and 7 being Sunday
getOccurrencesOfDayThisYear(2)
```

There might be a more sophisticated way of performing this through various moment methods.